Sorting numbers mixed with text in xslt
I need to sort a set of documents using attribute 'd' in ascending order. But in this attributes numbers mixed with letters.
Attributes could be like:
d="11A-1-000003" d="11-1-000008a" d="11-16-000009" d="11-1C-000008" d="11-9-000002" d="12-1-000008a" d="11-15-00014" d="13-1-000007a" d="11-15B-00014a" d="11-24-00043a" d="11-3-000023" d="11-3-000023a" d="11-3-000023b"
I tried different solutions, but have no luck, order is not correct.
<xsl:sort select="normalize-space(@d)" data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order="upper-first"/>
<xsl:sort select="replace(normalize-space(@d), '[^\d]', '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(normalize-space(@d), '-')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(@d), '-'), '-')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-after(normalize-space(@d), '-'), '-')" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(normalize-space(@d), '-')" data-type="text"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(@d), '-'), '-')" data-type="text"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(substring-after(normalize-space(@d), '-'), '-')" data-type="text"/>

<xsl:sort select="number(tokenize(@d, '-')[1])" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="number(tokenize(@d, '-')[2])" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="number(tokenize(@d, '-')[3])" data-type="number"/>
<xsl:sort select="tokenize(normalize-space(@d), '-')[1]"/>
<xsl:sort select="tokenize(normalize-space(@d), '-')[2]"/>
<xsl:sort select="tokenize(normalize-space(@d), '-')[3]"/>

Actual result is that: 11-3-000023 is after 11-24-00043a but should be after 11-2,
11-1C-000008 is after 11-15B-000008 but should be after 11-1
The expected result is that numbers should have numbers should take precedence over letters.
Numbers are chapters, letters are subchapters.
As an example expected result is:
d="11-1-000008a" d="11-1C-000008" d="11-3-000023" d="11-3-000023a" d="11-3-000023b" d="11-9-000002" d="11-15-00014" d="11-15B-00014a" d="11-16-000009" d="11-24-00043a" d="11A-1-000003" d="12-1-000008a" d="13-1-000007a"

The answer is going to depend on what collations your chosen XSLT processor supports. So we need to know which processor you are using. If the processor doesn't support an alphanumeric collation, then you will have to break up the strings into multiple sort keys, perhaps adding leading zeroes where necessary.

Here's a solution which uses a regular expression to parse the @d values into six separate tokens (numeric, and non-numeric), and sorts the documents with a separate xsl:sort for each one of those tokens.
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="true"/>

  <xsl:template match="documents">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- regular expression parses @d values into 6 tokens:
      a numeric token, an optional non-numeric token, an ignored hyphen, 
      a numeric token, an optional non-numeric token, an ignored hyphen, 
      a numeric token, an optional non-numeric token. 
       -->
      <xsl:variable name="parser">(\d+)([^\d]*)-(\d+)([^\d]*)-(\d+)([^\d]*)</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$1')" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$2')"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$3')" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$4')"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$5')" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="replace(@d, $parser, '$6')"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Input:
<documents>
   <document d="11A-1-000003"/>
   <document d="11-1-000008a"/>
   <document d="11-16-000009"/>
   <document d="11-1C-000008"/>
   <document d="11-9-000002"/>
   <document d="12-1-000008a"/>
   <document d="11-15-00014"/>
   <document d="13-1-000007a"/>
   <document d="11-15B-00014a"/>
   <document d="11-24-00043a"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023a"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023b"/>
</documents>

Output
<documents>
   <document d="11-1-000008a"/>
   <document d="11-1C-000008"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023a"/>
   <document d="11-3-000023b"/>
   <document d="11-9-000002"/>
   <document d="11-15-00014"/>
   <document d="11-15B-00014a"/>
   <document d="11-16-000009"/>
   <document d="11-24-00043a"/>
   <document d="11A-1-000003"/>
   <document d="12-1-000008a"/>
   <document d="13-1-000007a"/>
</documents>


You may want to tweak the regex or use other string functions for each xsl:sort/@select for an equivalent parse, but I defined just one regex here for clarity of exposition. And in fact the regex (\d+)([^-]*)-(\d+)([^-]*)-(\d+)(.*) is slightly more efficient though not as clear to read.

This solution works for me. Thanks a lot for help, @ConalTuohy
